# Problem to find ID number from min & max values

Tags: c, max, min

So I am trying to make a simple program that reads integers of values and ID number so the output will be minimum maximum of the value and its maxID minID number. The first integer of the input file will indicate how many more input will be read in loops. My program compiles without any problem and minimum maximum output are correct however,the output of ID numbers are wrong. Could anyone help me with diagnose this issue? Sorry for my silly question, I am new in programming. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int val[100],id[100];
int i, max, min, size, idmax, idmin,minindex,maxindex;

printf("Enter how many IDs: ");
scanf("%d", &size);

printf("Enter ID numbers and values:\n");
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    scanf("%d %d", &id[i], &val[i]);
}


max = min = val[0];

for(i=1; i<size; i++)
{
    if(val[i] > max)
    {
        max = val[i];
        maxindex = i;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
          if(id[i]==maxindex){
            idmax=id[i];
          }
        }
      }

    if(val[i] < min)
    {
        min = val[i];
        minindex = i;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
          if(id[i]==minindex){
            idmin=id[i];
          }
        }
    }
}

printf("Max number = %d with ID number = %d\n", max, idmax);
printf("Min number = %d with ID number = %d\n", min, idmin);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Edit the question and give examples of input and expected and actual output

Comment: You don't need `max`, `min`, `idmax`, or `idmin`. All you need are `minindex` and `maxindex`. For example, the comparison should be `if (val[i] > val[maxindex])`

Comment: You are also using the same variable, `i` for the inner and outer `for` loops - this will cause some unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the problem more complicated than it actually is. When running through the ;list, you can simply update the `idmax` or`idmin` value whenever you update the corresponding `max` or `min`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int val[100], id[100];
    int i, max, min, size, idmax, idmin;/// No longer need these: minindex, maxindex;

    printf("Enter how many IDs: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("Enter ID numbers and values:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &id[i], &val[i]);
    }

    max = min = val[0];
    idmin = idmax = id[0];/// Initialize IDs similarly to min and max

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (val[i] > max) {
            max = val[i];
            idmax = id[i];/// Only need to change this when max changes
        }
        if (val[i] < min) {
            min = val[i];
            idmin = id[i];/// Only need to change this when min changes
        }
    }

    printf("Max number = %d with ID number = %d\n", max, idmax);
    printf("Min number = %d with ID number = %d\n", min, idmin);

    return 0;
}
```